# How can i style "echo apply_filters"

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, filters

With WordPress I have years of experience but with PHP I do not have much experience. I want the available product colors on the shop page and that's working! :)

[image: Colors]

But i want a text before the available colors and i want to style it.
I tried a lot of things but my knowledge is limited.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

This is the code right now:

```
function custom_display_post_meta() {

    global $product;

    $attr = array('pa_kleur');

    foreach($attr as $attribute) {

        $values = wc_get_product_terms(
            $product - > id,
            $attribute,
            array(
                'fields' =>
                'names'
            )
        );

        echo apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_attribute',
            wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ),
            $attribute,
            $values
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: You could use another echo before echoing the filter. Not sure what you mean though.

Answer (score 1):

`apply_filters` just calls any methods hooked to the filter, in this case `woocommerce_attribute`, and returns the output. You could do a couple of things to style this, here's one way:

```
    $filtered = apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_attribute',
        wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ),
        $attribute,
        $values
    );

    echo '<span class="attribute-' . esc_attr( $attribute ) . ">' . $filtered . '</span>';
```

This will create something like:

```
<span class="attribute-color">RSV</span>
```

Now, you can style this in CSS with a rule such as:

```
span.attribute-color {
    font-weight: bold;
    /* etc */
}
```

This is assuming the attribute's name is "color", but whatever it is you should now be able to target that particular bit of text and apply custom CSS to it.